# Reuse Pattern instance in Java

Tags: java, regex

My question is, if it is possible to reuse the compiled pattern using `Pattern.compile( )` when used with `String.matches( )`?

Because, in the docs it says,

> A `matches` method is defined by this class as a convenience for when a
>   regular expression is used just once. This method compiles an
>   expression and matches an input sequence against it in a single
>   invocation. The statement
>
> ```
> boolean b = Pattern.matches("a*b", "aaaaab");
> ```
>
> is equivalent to the
>   three statements above, though for repeated matches it is less
>   efficient since it does not allow the compiled pattern to be reused.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

It only says that when you use Pattern.matches it becomes less efficient. And I got confused on this part:

> An invocation of this method of the form `str.matches(regex)` yields
>   exactly the same result as the expression
>
> ```
> Pattern.matches(regex, str)
> ```

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches(java.lang.String)

So I am not sure if `String.matches` uses `Pattern.matches` and because of that I cannot reuse the compiled pattern again. I was actually planning to set the compiled pattern as a constant (for optimization purposes)

Comment: Well no, since you don't have access to compiled pattern when using `String.matches()`. And you're reading it wrong. It's telling you that because of that, `String.matches()` (and `Pattern.matches()`, which is the same thing) is less efficient than re-using a compiled pattern because it's compiling the pattern every time you use it.

Answer (score 10):

`Pattern.matches()` method is a static method so it cannot be used if you want to reuse a compiled pattern. A compiled pattern is an instance of `Pattern` class. `Pattern.matches()` compiles your regex every time it's used.

You can reuse your compiled pattern by storing an instance of `Pattern` class, e.g.:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^[a-z]+$", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE); // you can store this instance
```

You can then get a matcher for this pattern each time you want to use it

```
Matcher m = pattern.matcher("Testing");
```

Comment: Warning though about the "match trap" (`.matches()` considers the whole input and does not do "real" regex matching)

Comment: @fge Right, I removed it then as this is not really important for the answer. Better not to confuse people.

Comment: You might as well use a regex that matches your target string, to avoid creating new confusion.  It's very minor point, but I think it's worth the effort.

Comment: Can you reuse a matcher object after a match or mis-match? Like `m.find(); ... m.find(12); ... m.find(24);`